# How to include Qt libs (qwebview.h) in Linux?

Tags: linux, qt, qwebview

I am just starting to use the Qt library. I am trying to compile my very first test script with the following header:

```
#include <qwebview.h>
```

However it won't compile:

```
g++ main.cpp -o run.main
main.cpp:2:22: error: qwebview.h: No such file or directory
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:10: error: ‘QWebView’ was not declared in this scope
```

I do have the libs installed on my Linux Kubuntu machine:

```
$ locate qwebview
/usr/include/qt4/Qt/qwebview.h
/usr/include/qt4/QtWebKit/qwebview.h
/usr/lib/qt4/plugins/designer/libqwebview.so
```

I ran `ldconfig` once to make sure (I think) that the libs are seen, but apparently, it's not enough.

How to I set up my machine so that I can start compiling software with Qt?

Answer (score 6):

in you **[your_library].pro** file add

```
QT       +=  webkit
```

then

```
#include <QWebView>
```

should be sufficient to get this code:

```
QWebView *view = new QWebView(parent);
view->load(QUrl("http://qt.nokia.com/"));
```

compiled

hope this helps, regards

Answer (score 4):

First, use the proper case for the include:

```
#include <QWebView>
```

Then add the proper include path to the compiler:

```
g++ -c -I /usr/include/qt4 main.cpp
```

Then link against the appropriate libraries:

```
g++ -o main.run main.o -lQtCore -lQtGui -lQtWebKit
```

If this seems too complicated to you try using qmake...

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <QWebView> should work.
```